# ping: network unreachble although I have an IP through DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, ping

I am about to install Archlinux on a root server via VNC. For installation Archlinux needs an internet connection. If I run `ip addr` it seems to me that I get an IPv6 address via DHCP (every reboot it's a different one, but all are fe80::/64). Here is the output:

`sh
$ ip addr
1: lo [uninteresting, so skipped]
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:01:00:00:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::b056:977e:546c:1d41/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

I enabled and started `dhcpcd` manually, but the output remains the same. The problem is that I cannot reach any outside server. Pinging 8.8.8.8 or the IPv6 pendant 2001:4860:4860::8888 prints that the network is unreachable. I tried out some tips with revolv and rc.conf that I found while googling for some solution, but nothing worked so far, especially since I do not know anything about the provider's network architecture.

Comment: That is a link local address (not routeable). e.g. you do not have any IP address. Nevertheless, if you do not know your provider, is people here supposed to know?

Comment: It's like buying a phone at a store.  The lights may come on, but you won't be able to talk to anybody if you don't have phone *service.* This is a question about your Internet service, and how you connect to the Internet.

Comment: Your MAC address of `52:54:01...` - is this a virtual machine (KVM or QEMU or similar)?

Comment: is there any log output from dhcpcd ?  i.e. can you show any messages from `journalctl -u dhcpcd` ?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro If that IP was not given by the provider's router, where does it come from (just so I have more understanding)? The output of `route` is empty (beside first line with the table header).

@G-Man As I understand I have bought a rootserver and should get an IP from the provider as soon as I try to connect via DHCP. I already contacted the support, but I have to wait a bit.

@StephenHarris Probably. I don't think I have a dedicated machine.

@sourcejedi The command gives:
**-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-01-02 18:00:00 UC, end at Thu 2019-01-03 18:20:00 UTC
-- No entries --**

Comment: here's an explaination with more details about your (not usable for internet) IPv6 address: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6 . To summarize, on IPv6 it replaces IPv4's ARP.

Comment: If you install windows and them you get a ip, so maybe your network driver is missing the firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an IP address with which you can explore the outside world.

If you want to access 8.8.8.8, you will need an IPv4 IP address. That will show up as  something like:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a9:71:04:30:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.20/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

in your `ip addr` output. So no IPv4 address.

You also do not have an IPv6 address that you can use in the outside world. Your FE80-address won't make it past your first router. You probably do not have an IPv6 router on your network (at least, not one that uses stateless autoconfig).

Your logs also indicate that your dhcpcd does not get an IP address. From the comments, I understand that your provider should give you an IP via DHCP. Although a router can do DHCP, almost everyone in a larger network uses a separate DHCP-server. That allows them to keep central control over the IP addresses and it is also easier to automatically update their DNS.  We use Infoblox, but there are others as well.

All that the router does is convert your DHCP request broadcast on the local lan  to a unicast towards your DHCP server. (it is bad habit to refer to your own website, but https://ljm.home.xs4all.nl/dhcp/index.html gives a bit of an explanation)

Comment: Helped me the most :) Indeed, I have static network settings (which I did overlooked since they were in a deeper submenu) and no DHCP.